# Compute transition probability in n step in infinte markov chain

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains

I want to calculate the probability of transition in n step from state 0 to state 0 ($p_{00}^{(n)}$) in below Markov-Chain :

[image: Markov-Chain]

if self loop in state 0 doesn't exist, probability computed with Catalan Number.
but in this form, how can calculate?